# JOOQ How to convert JSON based on other column value?

Tags: java, jooq, jsonb

Let's say I have a table **customer(int id, type varchar, preferences jsonb)**.
The **type** can be `REGULAR`, `PREMIUM` etc. Based on the column type value the preferences JSON structure will be different.

While loading a customer record from database if **type=REGULAR** I want to convert it into `RegularCustomerPreferences` object type, and if **type=PREMIUM** I want to convert it into `PremiumCustomerPreferences` object type.

I have gone through several tutorials on using JOOQ JSON converters/Bindings..but they are one to one mapping and not conditional based (depending on another column value).

What is the ideal way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously cannot do this in a type safe way as the type of your `preferences` column would be `Field<RegularCustomerPreferences | PremiumCustomerPreferences>` (the union type), and Java doesn't currently support union types. So, you could bind a common `CustomerPreferences` super type to the column, perhaps, and downcast the value wherever it is consumed.

Binding the super type should be relatively easy. You will be implementing a [`Binding<Object, CustomerPreferences>`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/), which can handle both `RegularCustomerPreferences` and `PremiumCustomerPreferences` values. Specifically, your converter would look something like this:

```
public Converter<Object, CustomerPreferences> converter() {
    return new Converter<Object, CustomerPreferences>() {
        @Override
        public CustomerPreferences from(Object t) {
            if (some check here to see if this is a regular customer)
                return new RegularCustomerPreferences(t);
            else
                return new PremiumCustomerPreferences(t);
        }

        @Override
        public Object to(CustomerPreferences u) {
            return MyJSONTools.toJSON(u);
        }

        @Override
        public Class<Object> fromType() {
            return Object.class;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<CustomerPreferences> toType() {
            return CustomerPreferences.class;
        }
    };
}
```

The assumption here is that your JSON content allows for making the decision what type the JSON document should have, redundantly with the `type` column, because currently, as of version 3.11 and 3.12, jOOQ doesn't support multi-column data type bindings which read several values to base their data type conversion decisions on. This is a pending feature related to: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6124