# Is it possible to combine two database fields into one in JOOQ with customer generators?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm reading over the docs [custom generators](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-generatorstrategy/) and [data type rewrites](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/code-generation/data-type-rewrites/). It seems like it has a lot of flexibility. But is it possible to combine two db fields into one?

For example, for foreign exchange, I'd like to store two fields

```
budget.value, budget.currency
```

Could I somehow have JOOQ convert this to

```
Value getMonetaryValue() {
    return Value(this.value, this.currency);
}
```

Where in this case `Value` is a custom enum that I've created to support both value and currency.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54763138/521799)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.11, this isn't possible out of the box. There's a pending feature request and related features that will allow for supporting what JPA calls `@Embeddable` types:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6124