# How to store Enum class name and enum value in database

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I have a class with different enums, for example:

```
class EligibilityRule{
ProductEligibility productEligibility;
CountryEligibility countryEligibility
}

enum ProductEligibility{
PRODUCT_X,
PRODUCT_Y
}

enum CountryEligibility{
US,
IN,
CN
..
}
```

I want to store these different enum class name and their value to database table called `eligibility rule`, and my table schema looks likes this,

```
String id  => auto_increment id
String ruleType => enum class name (ex: ProductEligibility)
String ruleValue => enum value (ex: PRODUCT_X)
```

I am using JOOQ, in the past I had used forced type to just store the enum value. But, in this case I want to store enum class name and enum value. I also want to reconstruct the enum object when I query the records from db.

Are there any patterns I can follow or is there any functionality in JOOQ which I can extend to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

JOOQ supports [custom data types](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/). This means that you can define a `converter` for your database field which is then automatically mapped to your custom type upon loading. The database field will still be a `String`, but the generated `Record` for the field will contain a `Field<EligibilityRule>`. This means that you do not have to explicitly store the class name.

To do this, you must register your converter in the code generator (taken from the above docs page):

```
<database>

  <!-- Then, associate custom types with database columns -->
  <forcedTypes>
    <forcedType>

      <!-- Specify the Java type of your custom type. This corresponds to the Converter's <U> type. -->
      <userType>java.util.GregorianCalendar</userType>

      <!-- Associate that custom type with your converter. -->
      <converter>com.example.CalendarConverter</converter>

      <!-- Add a Java regular expression matching fully-qualified columns. Use the pipe to separate several expressions.

           If provided, both "expressions" and "types" must match. -->
      <expression>.*\.DATE_OF_.*</expression>

      <!-- Add a Java regular expression matching data types to be forced to
           have this type.

           Data types may be reported by your database as:
           - NUMBER              regexp suggestion: NUMBER
           - NUMBER(5)           regexp suggestion: NUMBER\(5\)
           - NUMBER(5, 2)        regexp suggestion: NUMBER\(5,\s*2\)
           - any other form

           It is thus recommended to use defensive regexes for types.

           If provided, both "expressions" and "types" must match. -->
      <types>.*</types>
    </forcedType>
  </forcedTypes>
</database>
```

See also the [custom data type binding](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/) that JOOQ supports.

---

> *I see what you mean, in my case I am not creating new database field for each enum instead they will be stored as rule_type and rule_value(key/value) pair, where the key is the class name and the value is the enum value.*

I see. Unfortunately, I do not think that it would be possible to do this in a type-safe manner. I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54763138/jooq-how-to-convert-json-based-on-other-column-value) answer is pretty much what you're asking - a binding of a special type based on column value.

Since you are using enums however, you cannot have them extend a superclass as in the above answer (since all Enums implicitly extend `java.lang.Enum` and Java does not support multiple-inheritance). You might however try to slightly refactor your code and have all your enums implement some interface, i.e. :

```
enum ProductEligibility implements Rule {...};
enum CountryEligibility implements Rule {...};
```

With `Rule` being:

```
interface Rule { String getRuleType(); String getRuleValue(); }
```

And then creating a converter like in the example in the docs page or in the separate linked answer.

Of course, this also means that your `Record`s would have a `Field<Rule>` field in them, not the specific type of the enum. If this is acceptable for you, it might be a possible way to go.

---

> I did not get this part, `Of course, this also means that your Records would have a Field<Rule> field in them, not the specific type of the enum.`. Does this mean I will still store two fields in db, rule_type and rule_value with CustomConverter for each one of them?

No. You would still have only one converter, of type `Converter<Object, Rule>`. This converter would return **either** `ProductEligibility` or `CountryEligibility`, but it can't return *both*.

So, if your database table had something like:

```
eligiblity_rules
------------------
id    user    type                              value 
234   223     com.foo.bar.ProductEligibility    PRODUCT_Y
856   855     com.foo.bar.CountryEligibility    US
```

Your converter would look something like this:

```
public Converter<Object, Rule> converter() {
    return new Converter<Object, Rule>() {
        @Override
        public Rule from(Object t) {
            // t here refers to the "value" db field above
            if (checkIsProductEligibilityRule())
                 return ProductEligibility.fromValue(...);
            else
                return CountryEligibility.fromValue(...)
        }

        // Other converter methods
    };
}
```

So in your `JOOQ`-based code, you would end up having:

```
EligibilityRuleRecord record = dslContext.selectFrom(ELIGIBILITY_RULE).where(...).fetchOne();
Rule rule = record.getValue();
```

Afterwards, if you want to use the specific rule type, you would need a check and a cast:

```
if (rule instanceof ProductEligibility) {
    ProductEligibility peRule = (ProductEligibility) rule; 
    ...
}
if (rule instanceof CountryEligibility) {
    CountryEligibility ceRule = (CountryEligibility) rule;
    ...
}
...
```

The only reason for the `type` database field is for selecting the correct data. Unfortunately, the Java code does not know (at compile-time) what the type is going to be, hence you will need the class checks at runtime every time you wish to do know that field's specific type.

Comment: It is possible in future multiple enum types have same enum value, so I want to explicitly store the enum class name.

Comment: Multiple enum types with identical values should be fine as long as the different enum types are mapped to different database fields. You still wouldn't need to store the class name.

Comment: I see what you mean, in my case I am not creating new database field for each enum instead they will be stored as rule_type and rule_value(key/value) pair, where the key is the class name and the value is the enum value.

Comment: I've updated the answer above with a potential solution. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: You last solution seems feasible! I did not get this part, 
```Of course, this also means that your Records would have a Field<Rule> field in them, not the specific type of the enum.```. Does this mean I will still store two fields in db, rule_type and rule_value with CustomConverter for each one of them?

Comment: I've updated the answer above. Does that explain things?

Comment: This gives me an idea but in the converter you have mentioned this method to find `checkIsProductEligibilityRule()` but I can't do it without knowing the `type` field in db. That is the missing piece.

Comment: You're right - the type is known only when selecting for that specific type (as you input the type in the `where(...)`. When fetching whole lists, you might try assigning either of the enums and catching any `IllegalArgumentException`s that occur. Not quite super clean, but should be possible. That is of course, provided that no two enums can share a value.

Comment: In that case however, I would *strongly* suggest having tests that fail if any enum value is present in more than one enum.